# How to launch a Background Worker at Owin Startup?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try to launch a background worker at launch of my Owin Startup, but it doesn't launch (or doesn't write in the log files, I made my own Log System).

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(InternalApi.Startup))]

namespace InternalApi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            LogSystem.Write("Le serveur a démarré");
            bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
            bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            bw.ReportProgress(1);
        }
        private void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            LogSystem.Write("TEST", LogType.DEBUG);
        }

        private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I tried to Write in the bw_doWork but I understood that it was in another thread so I think it was a problem. 
The first Write works but the one in bw_ProgressChanged doesn't work.

I don't understand why it's not even launching ?

Comment: Why use a `BackgroundWorker` in the first place. Its purpose is for usage in UI environments like winforms. Better use a Task. And, since you've asked for it, why did you write your own logging system? Have you tried setting a breakpoint and debug the code?

Comment: I tried use a Task, but It wasn't launching neither. Maybe a complete tutorial about it could help me

Comment: My Log System is for non-dev purposes.

Comment: You might want to take a look at something like https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx for it is a web environment.

Comment: You can try using Hangfire which an excellent library for the backgroud jobs and tasks with complete and easy to implement tutorials. Follow this https://www.hangfire.io/   link.

Comment: Hangfire needs a database...

Comment: yup thats true .... so you want something with no database ?

Comment: Yes, I can't figure out why it is so complicated to make a background job in ASP.NET.